# C# version of __FUNCTION__ macro

Tags: c#, .net, macros

Does anyone has a good solution for a C# version of the C++ __FUNCTION__ macro? The compiler does not seem to like it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using this instead.

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
```

C# doesn't have `__LINE__` or `__FUNCTION__` macros like C++ but there are equivalents

Comment: As this one is top and accepted, can you/someone add:
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString() will yield the params too so its not ambiguous in the face of overloads and that System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString() to give the C name (&namespace)

Comment: there is a #line metadata-macro, which is used to give debugging information. The compiler will inject them for you, so be careful using it in normal code!

Answer (score 8):

What I currently use is a function like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public string __Function() {
    StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    return stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
}
```

When I need __FUNCTION__, I just call the __Function() instead. For example:

```
Debug.Assert(false, __Function() + ": Unhandled option");
```

Of course this solution uses reflection too, but it is the best option I can find. Since I only use it for Debugging (not Tracing in release builds) the performance hit is not important.

I guess what I should do is create debug functions and tag them with

```
[ Conditional("Debug") ]
```

instead, but I haven't got around to that.

Thanks to Jeff Mastry for his [solution](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/dotnetquestions/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=6163) to this.

Comment: Fails with async

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there is no equivalent version of that macro in C#.  I don't consider the GetCurrentMethodName() solution equivalent to the C++ __FUNCTION__ macro.  Namely becase the C++ version is a compile time computation of the name.  For C# this is a runtime calculation and incurs a performance hit.

I'm not making any assumtions about the severity of the cost but there is one

Comment: True, it would be nice to have a compile-time solution.
For my purpose reflection is quite sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

The following should work, although it will be evaluated at runtime instead of during compilation.

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
public static string CallerName([CallerMemberName] string callerName = "")
{
    return callerName;
}
```

Usage example:

```
s_log.DebugFormat("{0}", CallerName());
```

The down side of using it is that every time you want to print the caller name, you need to jump to the function ==> time consuming & performance hit!
So, I use it for debugging perpose and if I need to print also in production code, I usually inline the function name into the log.Debug, e.g. :

```
s_log.Debug("CallerName");
```

HTH..

Answer (score 2):

This is added in .NET 4.5.

See @roken's answer here:

[Do __LINE__ __FILE__ equivalents exist in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696218/do-line-file-equivalents-exist-in-c)