# Objective-C xcode: Equivalent of __FILE__ and __LINE__ from C/C++?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

Same question as: [Do __LINE__ __FILE__ equivalents exist in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696218/do-line-file-equivalents-exist-in-c)

But for Objective-C in iPad/iPhone SDK Xcode?  This would really help my NSLog statement be a lot more readable over time.

Comment: Objective C is a superset of C.  All your favorite features of C work just fine.

Answer (score 11):

So even easier visually. Displays only the file name without a path. It is convenient to observe the terminal without text wrapping.

**Writing:**

```
NSLog(@"Log: %s %d", (strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ?: __FILE__ - 1) + 1, __LINE__);
```

**Output is:**

```
Log: file.m 340
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they do:

```
 NSLog(@"%s:%d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

Output is e.g.:

> /Path/to/file.m:42

Answer (score 6):

You can also simply use `@__FILE__`

Answer (score 1):

I would have to go back and look at the Objective C documentation, but my guess would be *"most certainly"* since these are core to the C Programming Language and Objective C is an extension of it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you cannot implicitly cast the string constant returned by **FILE** to a char *.

This throws up a compiler warning.  "Deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char *'".

The above should read:

```
NSLog(@"%s:%d", (char *) __FILE__, __LINE__);
```