# __FILE__ & __LINE__ predfined macros in XCode

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, macros, operator-overloading, new-operator

Is there some way to implement functionality of **FILE** , **LINE** Visual Studio macroses in XCode ? It is needed for overloading new & delete to find leaks, with info about in what file & line there was a memory allocation. Thanks

Comment: `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` and standard macros. How did you get them **not** to work in XCode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C x-code: Equivalent of \_\_FILE\_\_ and \_\_LINE\_\_ from C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760411/objective-c-x-code-equivalent-of-file-and-line-from-c-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`? They should work in Xcode.

The following works for me:

```
NSLog(@"%s %d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

You might also find `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` useful too.

Comment: I've found my mistake, sorry.

Comment: it just should be inline void* operator new(size_t size,const cahr* file,int line) instead  inline void* operator new(unsigned int size,const cahr* file,int line) Go to defintion option havent work for __FILE__ so I had a mistake

Comment: Perhaps in future you should post the relevant code that is causing you problems.  Your comment above seems to have little in common with your original question.  Glad you solved your problem though.