# How do I pass line number to a method

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, line-numbers

In Visual Stuido 2013, working in C# (.Net 4.5), how can I pass a line number to a method call.  I recall in C there was a #pragma lineNumber to do this, but searching on those terms brings up nothing.

I want to write a method something like this:

```
// unchecked code:
private void printResetStopwatch(int lineNumber)
{
   stopwatch.stop();
   System.Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString() + " at line " + lineNumber.ToString();
}
```

and I would call it something like

```
printResetStopwatch(#pragma lineNumber);
```

if #pragma was the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556767/how-to-get-current-line-number-for-example-use-at-messagebox-show

Comment: This answers it.  Thanks a bunch.  Promote this to an answer, if you would, so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: It would just be duplicate content. That answer can be easily found.

Comment: It wasn't easy for me.  I looked several minutes and never found it.  I was using the wrong terminology, so s/o autosearch did not help me in this case.

Comment: Try google next time. Possibly using site:stackoverflow.com too. SO's search is very naive and sucks big time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to attribute a parameter on the method with the `CallerLineNumberAttribute` and provide it with a default value.  C# will then fill it in with the line number of the caller

```
void Method(string message, [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0) { 
  ...
}

Method("foo");  // C# will insert the line number here
```

Note that there are actually a set of related attributes here that might interest you.  Here is a sample

```
public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
```

Full Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx

Note: This requires the C# 5.0 compiler which is included in VS 2013.

Comment: Note that this requires the new C# 5 compiler and .NET 4.5. You can get by with some fake attributes, but you do need the new compiler.