# Find the line number of console application?

Tags: c#

I have a program that uses Console.WriteLine(); to output to the user in many different locations in the program. Is there a way to get what line the last printed line of output is in the console application? Without incrementing a counter every Console.WriteLine();. For example, in the following code "Bar Foo" would have printed as line 4.
Here would be an example program:

```
Console.WriteLine("Foo");
Console.WriteLine("Foo Bar");
Console.WriteLine("Bar");
Console.WriteLine("Bar Foo");
```

output:

Foo

Foo Bar

Bar

Bar Foo

Comment: Very cood technique posted here: [How to get current line number - for example use at messagebox.show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556767/how-to-get-current-line-number-for-example-use-at-messagebox-show)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CallerLineNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerlinenumberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is introduce in `.Net 4.5`.
You may have something like this:

```
static void WriteLine(string message, [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(lineNumber + ": " + message);
}
```

And in your sourcecode you can simply call it like :

```
WriteLine("Foo");
WriteLine("Foo Bar");
WriteLine("Bar");
WriteLine("Bar Foo");
```

If you must use a lower version of .Net you can use :

```
static void WriteLine(string message)
{
    StackFrame callStack = new StackFrame(1, true);
    var lineNumber = callStack.GetFileLineNumber();
    Console.WriteLine(lineNumber + ": " + message);
}
```

And again you just need to call it :

```
WriteLine("Foo");
WriteLine("Foo Bar");
WriteLine("Bar");
WriteLine("Bar Foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

No you need something custom to keep track of it.
However you can internalize it and make your own class that wraps Console.WriteLine to avoid repeated counter logic.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, every time you do a Console.WriteLine(), the cursor moves as well. So you can use the position of the cursor as a 0-based index of the line number:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Foo" + (Console.CursorTop+1));
        Console.WriteLine("Foo Bar" + (Console.CursorTop + 1));
        Console.WriteLine("Bar" + (Console.CursorTop + 1));
        Console.WriteLine("Bar Foo" + (Console.CursorTop + 1));
```