# Add Line Number to Logger

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

[image]

I have created a very simple event logger.  Is there a way to programmatically add line number, in this case "1587", to the text string that is being written?

**This must be done with .NET 3.5 without PDB files**.

I am not trying to find the line number during execution, but only the line number as shown in Visual Studio at the time of compilation.  The thread shown above, "How do I get the current line number?" is not the answer to my question.

Comment: Hi @Wayne, you can try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556767/how-do-i-get-the-current-line-number

Comment: I've already looked at this thread.  I have to use Net 3.5, so the new caller attributes approach won't work.  The stackframe doesn't work either since I don't include the pdb files and the code is obfuscated.  I'm not trying to find the line number at execution time, but only add the specific line number found during compilation.

Comment: `I am not trying to find the line number during execution, but only the line number as shown in Visual Studio at the time of compilation.` AFAIK these are the same thing.  There is no other line number at runtime than the line number shown in visual studio at the time of compilation.