# Is there a C# equivalent to C++ __FILE__, __LINE__ and __FUNCTION__ macros?

Tags: c#

I have a C++ code that I'm trying to migrate to C#. Over there, on C++, i was using the following macros definition for debugging purposes.

```
#define CODE_LOCATION(FILE_NAME, LINE_NUM, FUNC_NAME) LINE_NUM, FILE_NAME, FUNC_NAME
#define __CODE_LOCATION__ CODE_LOCATION(__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
```

Are there similar constructs in C#? I know there are no macros in C#, but is there any other way to get the current file, line and function values during execution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do \_\_LINE\_\_ \_\_FILE\_\_ equivalents exist in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696218/do-line-file-equivalents-exist-in-c)

Comment: @JimFell: while this question was posted 3 years ago and the duplicate is dated 7 years ago, i think it doesn't matter :) - both answers provide the solution - might worth merging the answers...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using .net 4.5 you can use [CallerMemberName CallerFilePath CallerLineNumber attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerlinenumberattribute.aspx) to retrieve this values.

```
public void DoProcessing()
{
    TraceMessage("Something happened.");
}

public void TraceMessage(string message,
    [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
    [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
    [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}
```

If you are using older framework and visual 2012 you just need to declare them as they are in framework (same namespace) to make them work.

Answer (score 4):

I guess [`StackFrame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe) is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: it only works in Debug builds. In a production Release build, the file name and line number information doesn't exist. Also, the StackFrame object may be null in a release build, which would NullReferenceException to be thrown at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 4.5 there is a set of new attributes that you can use for this purpose: [Caller Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx)