# How to add filename in output command in C#

Tags: c#, filenames, partial-classes

I'm working on a group of client/server applications, who are constantly exchanging messages. In order to follow this, I've added the following line on every place a message is to be sent:

```
if (cfg_Following_Messages.Value != 0)
    log.Debug($"About to broadcast [{message.GetType().Name}]");
new OwnMessageHandler.BroadcastClientMessage(message).Execute();
```

That created a list, where I could follow all messages, being sent by the server. In top of that, as the `log.Debug()` is `NLog` related, I could also see the particular class, responsible for sending the message.

Now, there's a catch, because in the server application I'm working now, the entire application is based on one single `Manager` class, being spread over different files ("Manager.Order.cs", "Manager.Client.cs", ...) as follows:

File `Manager.<whatever>.cs`:

```
public partial class Manager{
...
```

So, even by changing the log command into:

```
log.Debug($"About to broadcast [{message.GetType().Name}] by [{this.GetType().Name}]");
```

, I still end up with something like:

```
2023-10-27 13:43:33.6548 | <Namespace>.Manager | About to broadcast [SpecificTypeOfMessage] by [Manager]
```

, which is not very useful.

I would like something like:

```
2023-10-27 13:43:33.6548 | <Namespace>.Manager | About to broadcast [SpecificTypeOfMessage] by [Manager.Specific.cs]
```

But how to do that?
[This other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696218) mentions things like Caller Information and `StackFrame`, but I prefer none of those:

- The `StackFrame` solution is about getting the entire call stack, at every time a message gets sent back and forth. Although it works correctly (`sf.GetFileName()` is tested and yields a correct filename), it looks to me as a huge performance drop.
- Caller Information `CallerFilePath` is wrong, as you can see here:

I have added `, [CallerFilePath] string filePath = ""` to the signature of my method, and in order only to have the filename, I've done the following:

```
string filename = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
```

This, however, yields `Manager.cs` instead of `Manager.Specific.cs`, so this is wrong (`filePath` is wrong to start with)!

Next to the fact that `Caller Information`'s information is wrong, I also prefer not to modify the signature of my methods.

Are there other ways to log the filename?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The partial class files are only known at compile time. At runtime there is only one single `Manager` class. The `CallerFilePathAttribute` seems not to be able to differentiate partial class files. But you know where the method is. So, can't you log `$"{nameof(Manager)}.Specific.cs"`. Note that it is easier to use `nameof(Manager)` than `this.GetType().Name`. The compiler will check that the parameter to `nameof` is existant and it will be subject to rename refactorings.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: thanks for your quick reply, but a typical action is that `Manager.Specific.cs` becomes that large that one decides to split it into `Manager.Specific1.cs` and `Manager.Specific2.cs` and maybe more, and I would like to avoid needing to modify more code than needed.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: in top of that, the fact that `CallerFilePathAttribute` looses track of its partial class seems to be a bug. Is this a known bug and in case yes, are there plans to solve it or is it already solved? In case yes, in which version of C# or .Net platform?

Comment: You could post the issue to the compiler team here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues?q=is%3Aissue+CallerFilePathAttribute+

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Ok. done: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/70619